# Kubernetes cluster working but getting this error from the NGINX controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Although the cluster is working as expected this error is somewhat troublesome.

Kubernetes Version: **v1.17.3**

> E0407 17:57:54.426952       1 reflector.go:123]
>   github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/nginx-ingress/internal/k8s/controller.go:341:
>   Failed to list *v1.VirtualServerRoute:
>   virtualserverroutes.k8s.nginx.org is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list resource
>   "virtualserverroutes" in API group "k8s.nginx.org" at the cluster
>   scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix the problem you have to  disable **list/watch** operations on virtualserver and virtualserverroutes - set the `--enable-custom-resources` flag to **false** in your deployment/daemonset manifest.

```
--enable-custom-resources
Enables custom resources (default true)
```

Take a look also at: [nginx-ingress-controller-configuration](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/command-line-arguments/#cmdoption-enable-custom-resources), [disabling-list-watch-virtualserver](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/802).