# Access K8s Services via Ingress

Tags: nginx, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

We have configured MetalLB since our K8s cluster is hosted on bare metal infrastructure. It seems to be running fine with all pods up and running.

```
[~]# kubectl get all -n metallb-system
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/controller-b78574c59-47qfv   1/1     Running   0          24h
pod/speaker-4q2vm                1/1     Running   0          24h
pod/speaker-m8kwk                1/1     Running   0          24h
pod/speaker-t4rvs                1/1     Running   0          24h

NAME                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/speaker   3         3         3       3            3           kubernetes.io/os=linux   24h

NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/controller   1/1     1            1           24h

NAME                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/controller-b78574c59   1         1         1       24h
```

We have configured ingress controller via helm from  https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/helm-chart-3.29.0 and updating `hostNetwork`,`ingressClass`,`kind` to `true`,`ingress-nginx`,`DaemonSet` respectively in file `values.yaml`. The helm installation seems to have worked fine with all daemonset pods running and an LB ip provided to created ingress controller service.

```
[~]# kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/devingress-ingress-nginx-controller-c2x42   1/1     Running   0          18h
pod/devingress-ingress-nginx-controller-wtmgw   1/1     Running   0          18h

NAME                                                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
service/devingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer     x.x.x.x         1.2.3.40     80:32386/TCP,443:30020/TCP   18h
service/devingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP        x.x.x.x           <none>        443/TCP                      18h

NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
daemonset.apps/devingress-ingress-nginx-controller   2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   18h
```

Now we have deployed two pods namely `nginx` with `LoadBalancer` service type & `nginx-deploy-main` with `ClusterIP` service type.

```
[~]# kubectl get all -n default
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-854cf6b4d7-lv5ss               1/1     Running   0          18h
pod/nginx-deploy-main-6b5457fbb5-7tg9z   1/1     Running   0          18h

NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
service/nginx                  LoadBalancer   x.x.x.x        1.2.3.41       8080:31101/TCP    18h
service/nginx-deploy-main      ClusterIP      x.x.x.x          <none>           80/TCP          18h

NAME                                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx               1/1     1            1           18h
deployment.apps/nginx-deploy-main   1/1     1            1           18h

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-854cf6b4d7               1         1         1       18h
replicaset.apps/nginx-deploy-main-6b5457fbb5   1         1         1       18h
```

Below is the ingress resource setup to access `nginx-deploy-main`.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: nginx-main.int.org.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nginx-deploy-main
          servicePort: 80
```

And the ingress resource seems to be created correctly pointing to `nginx-deploy-main` service.

```
[~]# kubectl get ing -n default
NAME                 CLASS   HOSTS                           ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
ingress-resource     nginx   nginx-main.int.org.com                    80      19h

[~]# kubectl describe ing/ingress-resource -n default
Name:             ingress-resource
Namespace:        default
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host                           Path  Backends
  ----                           ----  --------
  nginx-main.int.org.com
                                 /   nginx-deploy-main:80 (x.x.x.x:80)
Annotations:                     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
Events:                          <none>
```

Outside of K8s cluster, we have nginx set up serving as reverse proxy with domain int.org.com resolution.

Below is the nginx configuration which should help me hit url `http://nginx-main.int.org.com` and get response but the response returned is 404.

```
upstream nginx-main.int.org.com {
  server 1.2.3.40:80;     ## Ingress Controller Service IP
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name nginx-main.int.org.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://nginx-main.int.org.com;
  }
}
```

Now when I try to access nginx pod (**not nginx-main**) using its `LoadBalancer` Service IP with below configuration , its able to provide response and works just fine

```
upstream nginx.int.org.com {
  server 1.2.3.41:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name nginx.int.org.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://nginx.int.org.com;
  }
}
```

Am I missing something here with regards to Ingress Controller or Resource. Port Forwarding works fine and am able to access services using the same.

This really is a blocker and any help or documentation reference would be really useful .

Comment: when you do a `kubectl port-forward` to your `jenkins-master-service` do you get a response? And is your dns alias jenkins.int.org.com pointing to your nodes with the ingress service running on or your load balancer?

Comment: You mentioned your environment is `K8s cluster on bare metal setup`. How did you provision a LoadBalancer for your nginx-controller? Can you please share the output of `kubectl describe svc <nginx-service-name>` ? And lastly where is `jenkins.int.org.com` pointing to?

Comment: Our k8s cluster is not hosted on cloud. Its hosted on-premise. So basically ingress controller and ingress are within the k8s cluster. This nginx service is outside the k8s cluster and we have sub domain registered with int.org.com. So we want our client to hit url say jenkins.int.org.com and this nginx outside k8s should forward to ingress controller and serve the jenkins content. Currently this external nginx outside k8s cluster is able to reach jenkins via hostNetwork and configured subdomain

Comment: So the issue you're having is when you try to access `Jenkins` in a way of: `external nginx` -> `ingress controller on a hostPort` -> `jenkins-service` -> `Jenkins`. Does the `Jenkins` page shows when you 1. `$ kubectl port-forward to your Jenkins service`, 2. Directly connect to the `ingress-controller`. Also I'd reckon you could use `Service` of type `Loadbalancer` with a [metallb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) allocated IP.

Comment: I see that you've edited your question. From what I can see you've configured the `ingressClass` when provisoning `nginx-ingress` as `ingress-nginx` but in your `Ingress` resource you are using just `nginx`. Could you please change it to `ingress-nginx` and tell if it solved you issue? I'd reckon this could also be related to the lack of IP address in `$ kubectl get ingress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried with another Ingress Controller i.e. https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress and were able to make it work .

Below were the steps done .

```
[~] git clone https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/
[~] cd kubernetes-ingress/deployments
[~] git checkout v1.11.1
[~] kubectl apply -f common/ns-and-sa.yaml
[~] kubectl apply -f rbac/rbac.yaml
[~] kubectl apply -f common/default-server-secret.yaml
[~] kubectl apply -f common/nginx-config.yaml
[~] kubectl apply -f common/ingress-class.yaml
```

Created daemon-set pods with  extra environment argument i.e. `--enable-custom-resources=false` added in yaml due to below issue in controller logs

Refer : [Kubernetes cluster working but getting this error from the NGINX controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61086542/kubernetes-cluster-working-but-getting-this-error-from-the-nginx-controller)

```
[~] kubectl apply -f daemon-set/nginx-ingress.yaml
[~] kubectl get all -n nginx-ingress -o wide
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx-ingress-gd8gw   1/1     Running   0          3h55m   x.x.x.x      worker1          <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-kr9lx   1/1     Running   0          3h55m   x.x.x.x      worker2          <none>           <none>
 
NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE     CONTAINERS     IMAGES                                                  SELECTOR
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress   2         2         2       2            2           <none>          5h14m   nginx-ingress   nginx/nginx-ingress:1.11.1   app=nginx-ingress
```

Hit respective worker nodes at port 80 and a 404 response means its working fine.

Deployed a sample application using github link https://github.com/vipin-k/Ingress-Controller-v1.9.0/blob/main/hotel.yml and updated host entry within Ingress object to `hotel.int.org.com`

```
[~] kubectl create -f hotel.yaml
[~] kubectl get all -n hotel -o wide
NAME                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP            NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/hotel-65d644c8f7-bj597   1/1     Running   0          3h51m   x.x.x.x     worker1          <none>           <none>
pod/hotel-65d644c8f7-csvgp   1/1     Running   0          3h51m   x.x.x.x     worker2          <none>           <none>
 
NAME                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE     SELECTOR
service/hotel-svc   ClusterIP   x.x.x.x   <none>        80/TCP    3h51m   app=hotel
 
NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES                                                    SELECTOR
deployment.apps/hotel   2/2     2            2           3h51m   hotel        nginxdemos/hello:plain-text   app=hotel
 
NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS   IMAGES                                                    SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/hotel-65d644c8f7   2         2         2       3h51m   hotel        nginxdemos/hello:plain-text   app=hotel,pod-template-hash=65d644c8f7

[~] kubectl get ing -n hotel
NAME            CLASS   HOSTS                       ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
hotel-ingress   nginx   hotel.int.org.com            80      3h52m
[~] kubectl describe ing hotel-ingress -n hotel
Name:             hotel-ingress
Namespace:        hotel
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>) 
Rules:
  Host                       Path  Backends
  ----                       ----  --------
  hotel.int.org.com
                             /        hotel-svc:80 (x.x.x.x:80,x.x.x.x:80)
Annotations:                 Events:  <none>
```

Updated external nginx configuration with enabled domain resolution .

```
upstream hotel.int.org.com {
  server 1.2.3.41:80;  #worker1
  server 1.2.3.42:80;  #worker2
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name hotel.int.org.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://hotel.int.org.com;
  }
}
```

Restart nginx and verify able to access via browser its serving response from respective running hotel namespace daemonset pods.

```
[~]# curl hotel.int.org.com
Server address: x.x.x.x:80
Server name: hotel-65d644c8f7-bj597
Date: 28/Apr/2021:05:47:15 +0000
URI: /
Request ID: 28d5cfab4ea28beea49879422b7e8f4c

[~]# curl hotel.int.org.com
Server address: x.x.x.x:80
Server name: hotel-65d644c8f7-csvgp
Date: 28/Apr/2021:05:52:06 +0000
URI: /
Request ID: 4135cacf83f8bf41c9677104500e610b
```

Exploring with MetalLB too and will post solution once its works